# Custom Context Menu Item on any application window

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I am investigating customizing context menu actions for any window and wondering if this is possible?

The idea is to right click on a window and the custom menu item pops up. (I observed that browsers e.g Chrome, Edge; have their own custom actions when you right click their window)

Ps: I know this involves editing the registry. I was able to acheive adding a custom menu item for folders. I'm looking for the "Window" eqivalent

Comment: Are you asking how to modify the context menu of another application that you didn't build? I don't think you'll find any one solution fits all, and in any case, unless the application has an API for it, it's gonna require some ugly code.

Comment: Each app owns its menus. If you want to get involved, you'll have to see if the app has a plug-in model that lets you participate in the menu. (This is generally quite rare for an app to offer this feature.)

Comment: You mean in the context menu of the windows managed by Windows like [this](https://imgur.com/a/meFvXN8) or [this](https://imgur.com/a/NNgKLf6) right? 

I'm also interested in finding a solution for this. Obviously the application can add its own menu items (as Chrome does in my screenshot, and you noted in your question), but I would expect we could add items here with some registry trickery.

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Somewhat. Should you do it? No!

Internet Explorer actually had registry keys that would let you add custom menu entries. Other browsers do not, the correct solution for them is to develop [a browser extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions). The same extension can be coded to work in both Firefox and Chrome/Chromium-based browsers.

A generic mechanism is not possible but for classic win32 desktop applications you could probably do it with injection and hooks but this will require a fair bit of win32 and c/c++ experience to not create a crashy mess.

The most difficult bit would be any application that does not use normal `HMENU` menus. You might have to do per-app hacks and workarounds, it is just not going to be worth the trouble...